# scraping table from a site with multiple tables into r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I practicing getting tables off of websites into R. It feels like each individual website requires its own unique strategies to do so. I've had a few, but I am stumped by this one: https://www.cbssports.com/fantasy/football/rankings/ppr/top200/

How would you go about getting one (or all four) of these tables into R, presumably using the rvest package.

Answer (score 2):

```
pacman::p_load(rvest, tidyverse)

url <- "https://www.cbssports.com/fantasy/football/rankings/ppr/top200/"

# get the html
read_html(url)->html

# get the author names
authors <- html_nodes(html, "[itemprop='name']") |> html_text2() |> tail(-1)

# create the dataframe
data.frame(
  rank = html_nodes(html, ".rank") |> html_text2(),
  name = html_nodes(html, ".player-name") |> html_text2(),
  team_postion_cost = html_nodes(html, ".team") |> html_text2(),
  bye = html_nodes(html, ".player-stats") |> html_text2()
) %>% 
# add the author column
 {mutate(., authors = rep(authors, each = nrow(.)/length(authors)))} |>

 # separate the team_position_cost column into the separate columns
 separate_wider_delim(team_postion_cost, delim = " ", names = c("team", "position", "cost")) |>
  mutate(
    position = as.factor(position),
    team = as.factor(team),
    cost = as.integer(str_remove(cost, "\\$")),
    bye = as.integer(bye))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 800 × 7
   rank  name         team  position  cost   bye authors  
   <chr> <chr>        <fct> <fct>    <int> <int> <chr>    
 1 1     J. Jefferson MIN   WR          34    13 Consensus
 2 2     J. Chase     CIN   WR          33     7 Consensus
 3 3     C. McCaffrey SF    RB          34     9 Consensus
 4 4     A. Ekeler    LAC   RB          31     5 Consensus
 5 5     T. Hill      MIA   WR          30    10 Consensus
 6 6     C. Kupp      LAR   WR          30    10 Consensus
 7 7     B. Robinson  ATL   RB          27    11 Consensus
 8 8     S. Diggs     BUF   WR          26    13 Consensus
 9 9     T. Kelce     KC    TE          23    10 Consensus
10 10    S. Barkley   NYG   RB          26    13 Consensus
# ℹ 790 more rows
```

Comment: Oops yes, I somehow lost it in copying it over! Updated it. Thanks for the catch @QHarr :-)